# Handling null with?

Tags: c#, null

Hi, I am getting the following error message when trying to handle a null value using the ?? coalesce operator, any idea why?

Unable to cast object of type `System.DBNull` to type `System.String`

```
using(SqlDataReader rMemo = cmdUMemo.ExecuteReader())
{
      while (rMemo.Read())
      {                        
           String Title = (String)rMemo["UpdateTitle"] ?? "";
           lblUTitle.Text = Title;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `as` keyword:

```
String Title = rMemo["UpdateTitle"] as String ?? "";
```

The `DBNull` type cannot be explicitly converted to a string, however the `as` keyword will *attempt* to make the conversion, and if it fails, return a `null`.  That `null` would then be coalesced to `""` using the `??` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Compare it [DBNull.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and return empty string like:

```
 String Title = rMemo["UpdateTitle"] == DBNull.Value ? "" :
                                           rMemo["UpdateTitle"].ToString();
```

**Another** way of doing the same could be to use `Convert.ToString` it will return empty string for `DBNull.Value`

```
String Title = Convert.ToString(rMemo["UpdateTitle"]);
```

Remember `DBNull.Value.ToString()` means an Empty String. So you can check whether your returned rows have a column `UpdateTitle` and then call `Convert.ToString` like:

```
string Title = rMemo["UpdateTitle"] != null ? Convert.ToString(rMemo["UpdateTitle"]) 
                                              : "";
```

Applying `Convert.ToString` on `null` values would return `null` not an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

A nice easy way to handle this is to write an extension method, which can then be used all over the place:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public String ToStringOrEmpty(this object obj)
    {
        if(obj == null)
           return String.Empty;

        return obj.ToString();
    } 
}
```

Then you can simply call it like this making your code nice and readable:

```
String Title = rMemo["UpdateTitle"].ToStringOrEmpty()
```